# Consistent legend colors with qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following data frame:

```
x = read.table(text = 'Lo Re Pe
1 T 33
1 F 22
1 H 11
2 T 22
2 F 22', header = TRUE)
```

and the following plot:

```
qplot(factor(Lo), data=x, geom='bar', fill=Re, weight=Pe, 
      xlab='L', main='Title', ylab='Pe')
```

Now consider this data frame:

```
x <- read.table(text = 'Lo Re Pe
1 D 33
1 K 22
2 D 22
2 K 22', header=TRUE)
```

with the same `qplot` statement.

The colors assigned to each `Re` value are not consistent between the plots, so it is difficult to compare the plots directly.

How do I specify that `Re` value `T` should always be "Red", for example, and that `Re` value `F` should always be "Blue", for example, so that the `qplot` command always uses **consistent** colors for each `Re` value, regardless of the contents of the data frame? There are a finite and known number of values for `Re`, so I could specify them all.

I tried the following when the data frame contained values `T`, `F` and `H`:

```
qplot(factor(Lo), data=x, geom='bar', fill=Re, weight=Pe, 
      xlab='Loci', main='Title', ylab='Pe', 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("Blue","Red","Green"),labels=c("T","F","H")))
```

but R reports an error about incorrect length and does not produce a plot.

The solution would ideally allow me to specify colors for all possible values of `Re`, even though all of these may not be present in the data frame.

Comment: Maybe you want to provide us with a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Done. Reworked question completely.

Comment: I think this will work OK if you just make sure to use factors with the same levels and `scale_colour_discrete(drop=FALSE)`

Comment: @BenBolker: I'd like to use the same `qplot` statement regardless of the contents of the data frame, so the `qplot` would have to list the color for each of the possible values of `Re`.

Comment: Ben is right. You don't need to specify the palette. The colours will be unique and consistent as long as `x$Re` is defined with the whole list of levels each time.

Comment: But `x$Re` is different each time the plot is run depending on the input data. Where/how do I include the other `Re` values if there are no data for them? And I wouldn't want the non-existent values to appear in the legend.

Comment: Not wanting the non-existent values to appear in the legend makes the problem a lot harder.  If you're not worried about that you can just say (e.g.) `x$Re <- factor(x$Re,levels=c("T","F","H","D","K"))` and use `scale_colour_discrete(drop=FALSE)`

Comment: I just want to be able to compare different runs of the `qplot` with different data, such that "T" in one run always has the same color as "T" in the second run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly possible using the modular nature of `ggplot`. I'm going to recommend that you drop `qplot`, though, and switch to using `ggplot()`. It will cost you nothing and will be more convenient in the long run, as it is more suited to doing "complicated" things.

Let's start with your two data sets:

```
x1 = read.table(text = 'Lo Re Pe
1 T 33
1 F 22
1 H 11
2 T 22
2 F 22', header = TRUE)

x2 <- read.table(text = 'Lo Re Pe
1 D 33
1 K 22
2 D 22
2 K 22', header=TRUE)
```

Now here's your first plot, but translated into `ggplot()`:

```
p <- ggplot(x1,aes(x = factor(Lo))) + 
        geom_bar(aes(fill = Re,weight = Pe)) + 
        labs(x = 'L',y = 'Pe') + 
        opts(title = 'Title')
```

To keep the color consistent across plots, and to prevent unused colors from appearing in the legend, we will simply create a master color key, and pass only the needed subset of it to our scale:

```
color_key <- c('red','blue','green','black','orange')
#If Re is a character variable:
names(color_key) <- unique(c(x1$Re,x2$Re))
#If Re is a factor:
names(color_key) <- unique(c(as.character(x1$Re),as.character(x2$Re)))
```

(You could also do something similar using the `levels` function, but I wanted to guard against including levels that do not appear in the data set.)

Obviously, you can choose whatever colors you like. Now I can customize the `fill` scale for our plot `p` by passing only that segment of `color_key` that is relevant to `scale_fill_manual`:

```
p + scale_fill_manual(values = color_key[names(color_key) %in% x1$Re])
```

[image]

Additionally, if your plots all really do have the same structure, we don't even need to replicate the `ggplot` call over and over. We can simply apply our plot `p` to a new data set:

```
p1 <- p %+% x2
```

And then add the `fill` scale in the same manner:

```
p1 + scale_fill_manual(values = color_key[names(color_key) %in% x2$Re])
```

[image]

Finally, let's mix and match ourselves a new data set:

```
x3 <- rbind(x1[1:2,],x2[3:4,])
```

Same process works again:

```
p3 <- p %+% x3
p3 + scale_fill_manual(values = color_key[names(color_key) %in% x3$Re])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am working through it now. The line starting with `p + scale_fill_manual` gives error `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 3 needed but only 0 provided.` and no plot.

Comment: @SabreWolfy You may not have run the code in my post _exactly_ as it appears, because it all runs fine for me. Run each piece in sequence (including generating `x1` and `x2`) and check that each had run correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have done that :) I copied and pasted each section in order. The `unique` command is only returning 3 values. I'm trying to find out why now.

Comment: @SabreWolfy It's probably because your versions of the `Re` variables are factors, not characters. I'll edit with an adjustment momentarily.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `as.character`, but in the wrong place :) Your edit has resolved this.

Comment: One more question: please point me in the right direction to read about the `%+%` operator. It's hard to search for these characters.

Comment: ?'%+%' but there currently aren't any examples there. It only does one thing really, "add" a new data frame to an existing plot object, recreating the plot with the new data frame.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Didn't have the quotes around it when I tried with `?` :)